# Best method to measure execution time in Android?

Tags: java, android

What is best method to measure execution time of Android code snippet?

I have a section of code before and after which I want to place timestamps to find out it's execution time (e.g. one in `onCreate()` and another in `onDestroy()` method of activity).

I have tried `Time.toMillies(false)`, but it only returns seconds to me (with constant `000` at the end). I also tried two java functions: `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`.
First one returns milliseconds of epoch time, second doesn't.

What would be the best way to measure execution time and get good precision?

Answer (score 99):

What about **TimingLogger**?

From [TimingLogger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html) documentation:

```
TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger(YOUR_TAG, "methodA");
// ... do some work A ... 
timings.addSplit("work A");
// ... do some work B ... 
timings.addSplit("work B");
// ... do some work C ... 
timings.addSplit("work C");
timings.dumpToLog();
```

and the dump will look like:

```
     D/TAG     (3459): methodA: begin
     D/TAG     (3459): methodA:      9 ms, work A
     D/TAG     (3459): methodA:      1 ms, work B
     D/TAG     (3459): methodA:      6 ms, work C
     D/TAG     (3459): methodA: end, 16 ms
```

Do not forget to enable your tag by running: `adb shell setprop log.tag.YOUR_TAG VERBOSE`

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `setprop`. I don't understand why `VERBOSE` is necessary when `dumpToLog()` uses `Log.d()`, but it apparently is.

Comment: `adb shell setprop log.tag.YOUR_TAG VERBOSE` in your example it is `adb shell setprop log.tag.TAG VERBOSE` right? If that is the case I don't understand why it doesn't work. I see no log

Comment: `YOUR_TAG` in the example should be whatever string you used to initialize the `TimingLogger`. Example: `new TimingLogger("MyApp", "methodA");` use `adb shell setprop log.tag.MyApp VERBOSE`

Comment: @LarsH The reason `VERBOSE` is necessary is because when `TimingLogger` is initialized, the `reset()` method only enables the logger if `Log.isLoggable(mTag, Log.VERBOSE)` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: My trick is that I clone TimingLogger class and make it does not check for VERBOSE. This may help.

Comment: use `import android.util.TimingLogger;` if TimingLogger was not found.

Comment: fortuneteller TimingLogger has been `deprecated` since API level 30.

Comment: You can check out Snippet a library that does something like this.
https://github.com/microsoft/snippet-timekeeper

Comment: Note :`timings.dumpToLog();` is required at the end to print out the log to Android Studio Logcat.

Comment: Do not forget to enable your tag by running: adb shell setprop log.tag.YOUR_TAG VERBOSE

Answer (score 27):

> What would be the best way to measure execution time

`System.nanoTime()` is probably a good choice. Jake Wharton is using that with [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo), for example.

> and get good precision

This is not strictly possible, as anything can happen on the device while your method is executing. Those external factors will affect your time measurements, by stealing away CPU time, tying up I/O channels, etc. You need to average your tests across several runs to try to average out those external factors, and accuracy/precision will suffer as a result.

And, as Marcin Orlowski notes, to actually figure out *why* you are consuming certain amounts of time, use Traceview.

Comment: Technically it's only _accuracy_ that suffers.  Precision is always nanoseconds.

Answer (score 23):

**Kotlin Developers**

To get the elapsed time in MilliSeconds:

```
val elapsedTime= measureTimeMillis {
            // call you method from here or add any other statements
}
```

To get the time in NanoSeconds:

```
val elapsedTime= measureNanoTime {
            // call you method from here or add any other statements
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I usually use  `System.nanoTime()` for quick Measurement.

A simple Setup like this

```
   val startTime =   System.nanoTime()

    //DO SOMETHING

   Log.e("Measure", TASK took : " +  ((System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000)+ "mS\n")
```

Answer (score 8):

What you ask about is called [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29), and there're tools to help you with that on Android as well. See article [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) on official developer site.

Comment: totally agree, although when in profiling mode the app is slower, the information about thread, methods and percentage of time spent on them is worth it.
Otherwise, I'd say System.currentTimeMillis() is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer for folks developing android applications with ***Kotlin***; also this is the only answer that comes up in search as first main result for ***code performance of Kotlin in android***.

A simple Kotlin answer is already present on this thread for measuring perf in ms and nanosec -
*but my solution will help folks who want to log and execute function inline same time after execution completes, also is a cleaner approach when there is multiple performance measurement involved of different functions*

Create functions as such:

```
//the inline performance measurement method
private inline fun <T> measurePerformanceInMS(
        logger: (Long) -> Unit,
        function: () -> T)
: T {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result: T = function.invoke()
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    logger.invoke( endTime - startTime)
    return result
}

//the logger function
fun logPerf(time: Long){
    Log.d("TAG","PERFORMANCE IN MS: $time ms ")
}

//the function whose performance needs to be checked
fun longRunningFunction() : Int{
    var x = 0
    for (i in 1..20000) x++
    return x
}
```

This way you can keep logging, performance computation and function execution under a single function call and no code replication needed.

If you require nano second measurement then use `System.nanoTime()`

**USAGE** :

```
val endResult = measurePerformanceInMS({time -> logPerf(time)}){
            longRunningFunction()
        }
```

**NOTE** : here the *'endResult'* will carry the result of function whose performance was being measured.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers there is a library called Snippet that could be used to measure the execution times.
It also takes care of logging and putting all the relevant execution on the logs. It also takes care of measuring non contiguous spans of code, that could span across multiple methods and even files. Below is how it deals with contiguous code. We can add splits within a measurement too.

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    // The capture API can be used to measure the code that can be passed as a lambda.  
    // Adding this lambda captures the class, line, thread etc automatically into the logcat.
    // This cannot be use for code that returns a value as the lambda declared for closure is 
    // is a non returning lambda. For the case that could return a value and are a little complex // use the log-token based API demonstrated below.  
    
    // Captures the code as a lambda.  
    Snippet.capture(()-> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)); 
}
```

The code will also become no-op in the release builds.

To configure it, just add the below code in the application onCreate() as early as possible.

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
        Snippet.install(new Snippet.MeasuredExecutionPath());      
        Snippet.newFilter("SampleFilter");      
        Snippet.addFlag(Snippet.FLAG_METADATA_LINE | Snippet.FLAG_METADATA_THREAD_INFO);      
}
```

https://github.com/microsoft/snippet-timekeeper