# How to get TimingLogger log to LogCat

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat, execution-time

I would like to use TimingLogger to log the execution time of code, but the logs don't show in LogCat.

I have tried to use `adb shell setprop log.tag.YOUR_TAG VERBOSE` according to  [Best method to measure execution time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913762/best-method-to-measure-execution-time-in-android/35553778) . Since adb is not listed in path variable, I had to cd to respective folder in terminal and execute it from there. 
After executing the command, following response is written:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at txp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Code used to create the logs:

```
TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger("MyTag", "genext");
//some code
timings.addSplit("prepared");
//some code
timings.addSplit("loaded");
timings.dumpToLog();
```

with `adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag VERBOSE`

Do I need to have adb set as a path variable, to function properly? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. 
Verbose log messages were not showing due to Huawai phone configuration, no problem with Android/Android Studio.
If you encounter a similar problem, this helped to solve it:
[Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app/18395092#18395092)